# Is there any way we can use 'md5' encoding in Bot Framework Composer?

Tags: json, botframework, md5, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

[you can view my error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSXKa.png)

I tried using hash_md5(), but its showing me error.
Please help me to convert string to md5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-built function available, you write a custom action to handle this.

here are the steps on how to implement [custom action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pbINPIYfd4&list=PL-PgMmMmma8D5WRvwKhzQrEEM5FkOUcy5&index=16)

Comment: can anyone guide how to write a custom action for md5 conversion??

Comment: Updated video link on how to implement custom action in bot composer, you can write  md5 conversation your own,

Comment: [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
PS C:\Users\Prateek Kumar\Downloads\botluisproject\botluisproject\testbot\testbot\schemas> .\update-schema.ps1
Running schema merge.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Prateek Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\botframework-cli\bin\run'
←[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)←[39m

Comment: plz solve this error

Comment: Install Bf tools ?

Comment: yes sir already installed

Comment: Sir, I have set variable property in dialog.myvariabe which is concatenating and the multiple parameters now  I want this variable to pass in my custom action. Please let me know how I can pass this variable as parameter in that. TIA